# How to fix importing issues with Django External DB? [AssertionError:]

Tags: python, django, database

I connected my external postgreSQL database to Django and ran inspect db to import models into my app. While migrating the changes, I am getting the following errors:

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\OneDrive - XTRACAP FINTECH INDIA PRIVATE LIMITED\Desktop\XtraCap\django_api\api\models.py", line 1092, in <module>
    class Holidays(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 320, in __new__
    new_class._prepare()
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 333, in _prepare
    opts._prepare(cls)
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 254, in _prepare
    model.add_to_class('id', auto)
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\prateek.jain\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2393, in contribute_to_class
    assert not cls._meta.auto_field, (
AssertionError: Model api.Holidays can't have more than one auto-generated field.
```

If I hash out the Auto generated primary keys to check I get the following errors for all my models:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
api.AddressMaster.address_owned_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.address_owned_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.address_type'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.address_owned_by' or 'AddressMaster.address_type'.
api.AddressMaster.address_type: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.address_type' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.address_owned_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.address_type' or 'AddressMaster.address_owned_by'.
api.AddressMaster.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.updated_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.created_by' or 'AddressMaster.updated_by'.
api.AddressMaster.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.created_by' or 'AddressMaster.user'.
api.AddressMaster.updated_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.updated_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.created_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.updated_by' or 'AddressMaster.created_by'.
api.AddressMaster.updated_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.updated_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.updated_by' or 'AddressMaster.user'.
api.AddressMaster.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.created_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.user' or 'AddressMaster.created_by'.
api.AddressMaster.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AddressMaster.updated_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AddressMaster.user' or 'AddressMaster.updated_by'.
api.AgentKycMapping.agent_user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AgentKycMapping.agent_user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AgentKycMapping.created_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AgentKycMapping.agent_user' or 'AgentKycMapping.created_by'.
api.AgentKycMapping.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AgentKycMapping.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AgentKycMapping.agent_user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AgentKycMapping.created_by' or 'AgentKycMapping.agent_user'.
api.AgentUserMapping.agent_user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AgentUserMapping.agent_user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AgentUserMapping.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AgentUserMapping.agent_user' or 'AgentUserMapping.user'.
api.AgentUserMapping.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AgentUserMapping.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AgentUserMapping.agent_user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AgentUserMapping.user' or 'AgentUserMapping.agent_user'.
api.AuditMaster.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AuditMaster.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AuditMaster.updated_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AuditMaster.created_by' or 'AuditMaster.updated_by'.
api.AuditMaster.updated_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AuditMaster.updated_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AuditMaster.created_by'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AuditMaster.updated_by' or 'AuditMaster.created_by'.
```

Can someone help me resolve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that a model (or multiple models) contain two (or more) relations to the same model, for example:

```
class AddressMaster(models.Model):
    # …
    address_owned_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the problem is that for each such relation, Django spans a conceptual relation in reverse: a way to access all the `AddressMaster`s that are constructed/owned by that user. By default it will use `modelname_set` as name for that relation, but since you have two (or more) `ForeignKey`s to user, it means that for a user *`myuser`*, you thus have two relations with the same name, so what would `myuser.addressmaster_set.all()` return?

You thus will need to specify the names of the relations in reverse yourself. For example:

```
class AddressMaster(models.Model):
    # …
    address_owned_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='addresses_owned'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='addresses_created'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

to avoid a name clash. Likely there are a lot more of these clashes, hence you will need to introduce more `related_name=…`s to fix this problem.

Comment: Got it, how do I go about the auto generated primary key issue? Removing all primary keys might lead to a problem while creating relationships between different models

Comment: @PrateekJain: you don't. In django you can only use *one* primary key. While it has been proposed multiple times, they never moved away from the fact that models should have only *one* primary key. This is because a lot of other things assume this, for example a `DetailView` assumes the model has a single primary key, and that the url contains that view.

Comment: I understand. What I am still confused about is that all my models have only one Autogenerated key each while other keys are just Foreign Keys to create relationships. 

For the example code error I shared in the first part of the question, this is my model:

class Holidays(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    holiday = models.DateField()
    bypass_receivable = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta: 
        managed = False
        db_table = 'holidays'

I don't see two autogenerated keys here

Comment: @PrateekJaoin: well each model *needs* a primary key. If you don't specify a field with a primary key, Django wil define a field itself, so then the situation occurs that there are *two* `AutoField`s. You thus should mark the `id` as `primary_key=True`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks will try this out!

Comment: is there a way to fix the reverse accessor problems quickly? I have over a 100 tables and these issues are in almost all of them.

Comment: @PrateekJain: if you do not care about the related name, you can specify `related_name='+'` for all conflicting `ForeignKey`s/`ManyToManyField`s/`OneToOneField`s, this basically says that it should not generate a relation in reverse.

Comment: Thanks will do that